# Java Feign Fallback class

Tags: java, spring-boot, fallback, feign

I am using SpringBoot version 1.5.9.
I can’t understand why my Fallback class doesn’t work out.
Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

My Feign client:

```
@FeignClient(
        name = "prices",
        url = "${prices.url}",
        configuration = MyFeignConfig.class,
        fallbackFactory = FallbackClass.class
)
public interface PricesFeignClient {

    @GetMapping("/{userId}")
    PriceModel get(
            @PathVariable("userId") String userId
    );

}
```

Here is the fallback class:

```
@Component
public class FallbackClass implements FallbackFactory<PricesFeignClient> {

    @Override
    public PricesFeignClient create(Throwable cause) {
        return new PricesFeignClient() {

            @Override
            public PriceModel get(String userId) {
                System.out.println("LALALA");
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

In theory, my fallback method should work out if my Feign client returns an error.
Here in the Feign client in the files in ***prices.url*** I specified the wrong URL (simulated the situation that my remote service to which I am making a call is unavailable). Knowing my Feign client should return with an error and the Fallback class should be called in which in the console I should receive the message: ***"LALALA"***.

This message is not in the console: my Fallback class is not being called. Instead, I get an error stating that the requested resource was not found.

Please tell me what could be the problem? Can I make a mistake somewhere?

The thing is that now I'm trying to get my Fallback class to work. And then I want to call another Fagnet class in the Fallback class with a different URL so that it works out if my main service is unavailable.
Tell me, please. thanks

Comment: Do you have `feign.hystrix.enabled: true` set up in your application properties?

Comment: Yes, but it's not working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add to dependencies this for it to work (also don't forget to insert **feign.hystrix.enabled: true** as was said in the comments)

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.10.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```